# AWS bucket policy just for allowing to view the files but does not allow to download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to know if AWS has provided some S3 files viewer to view PDF, word files. Actually I don't want to allow users to download my files rather they can just view the files? Is it possible? If yes how? If not then is there any other solution for the same?

One solution I thought was, I can have an application running on EC2 server and then I can create an endpoint for S3 to EC2 and only that EC2 application can access the files but it will not allow users to download those files. But this will be a complex solution what I thought, is there any better way or does S3 or any other service provide such functionality?

Answer (score 2):

To Amazon S3, there is no difference between viewing and downloading. In both cases, the contents of the file must be downloaded to the client.

Where the difference lies is at the client end, and whether the data is displayed in your browser/application, or if it's saved to the hard drive. From Amazon S3's point of view (or any web server for that matter), the file was downloaded to your computer, plain and simple.

Allowing users to view PDFs in a browser, but not download them will be difficult:

1. Most PDF viewers allow you to save the PDF, and
2. The URL that the PDF viewer used to retrieve the PDF can be observed and re-used by a technical-enough person to download the file.

You may be able to use an S3 pre-signed URL that includes an expiry date, where the PDF viewer downloads and displays the PDF, but that single URL is only valid for a limited amount of time. For example, 5 minutes. After that time, the URL will fail.

Comment: Technically, all web content must be downloaded (or, in the case of streaming, "downloaded" in segments) before it can be viewed on the end user's device or browser.  Obfuscation of the process may deter the casual user but is not foolproof.